# Wix post build event order

Tags: msbuild, wix, visual-studio-2022

I have the following Wix project. In post build event I would like to use the target path, which is modified in `BeforeBuild` target. The modification is to create msi filename with assembly version. However, in post build event target is not modified yet and the value is based on `OutputName` only.

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk" Version="4.0.2" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputName>Server</OutputName>
    <Name>ServerInstaller</Name>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <DefineConstants>Debug</DefineConstants>
    <SuppressIces>ICE61;ICE57</SuppressIces>
    <BindFiles>false</BindFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\userve\userve.csproj">
      <Name>userve</Name>
      <Project>{b20b1c16-7dfd-40f4-a0cb-6b7bb227d10f}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
      <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
      <RefTargetDir>INSTALLFOLDER</RefTargetDir>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk" Version="4.0.2" />
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(SolutionDir)Control\bin\$(Configuration)\Control.dll">
      <Output ItemName="AssemblyInfo" TaskParameter="Assemblies" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(OutputName).%(AssemblyInfo.Version)">
      <Output PropertyName="TargetName" TaskParameter="Value" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)">
      <Output PropertyName="TargetFileName" TaskParameter="Value" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Output PropertyName="TargetPath" TaskParameter="Value" />
    </CreateProperty>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>echo $(TargetPath)</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

How to get modified `TargetPath` in post build event?

Comment: I suspect you have two issues. You are defining a property named `PostBuildEvent` which has the value of `"echo "`. Do you intend to create a property or are you trying to run a step after the build? MSBuild has two phases: evaluation and execution. The top level `PropertyGroup` and `ItemGroup` elements are processed during evaluation. Targets, including the `BeforeBuild` target, run during execution, after evaluation. `$(TargetPath)` is modifed by the `BeforeBuild` target after the `PostBuildEvent` property has been defined.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I am trying to run command after the build. "echo" is just a placeholder. I will use `TargetPath` in that command.

Comment: For testing create a target that redefines `AfterBuild` or that has `AfterTargets="AfterBuild"` and that uses a `Message` task to display `$(TargetPath)`, e.g. `<Message Text="echo $(TargetPath)" />`. Later, your command will need to be in this target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding,the issue may be caused by two reasons. One is that the target `BeforeBuild` is not run. Another is [Common macros for MSBuild commands and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170#list-of-common-macros) override issue.

1.You can specify a post build event from Project menu->click {ProjectName} Properties->Select Build > Events->Post-build Event. Visual Studio modifies your project file by adding the `PostBuild` target and the necessary MSBuild code to execute the steps you provided.
example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RunPostBuildEvent>Always</RunPostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Message Text="$(TargetPath)" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

Then build the project and watch the value of `$(TargetPath)` and see if it has been modified.

2.Rename the `TargetPath` to `TargetPath_customize`（different name from commonly used macros).

```
<CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
    <Output PropertyName="TargetPath_customize" TaskParameter="Value" />
</CreateProperty>
```

Docs Referred:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-events-page-project-designer-csharp?view=vs-2022

Hope it can help you.